# Class Design Question: Union of List<ChildStat> and AllStats

Tags: c#, linq, class

I have a Player class and a Stat class. The Player class has a List property where PlayerStat has a List and XP properties. I think my design is flawed because I am having trouble doing things that I think should be easy. I want to list out all Players and their XP for all Stats. Below are more details of the classes and the GetCompletePlayerStats method which is what I really don't like. I basically need to list out the XP for all stats for a Player, if the player doesn't have a stat then it should have an XP of zero. Any design help/suggestions would be appreciated.

```
public class Stat : EntityBase{
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual UnitOfMeasure Unit { get; set; }
  public virtual int UnitXP { get; set; }
}
public class Player : EntityBase{
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<PlayerStat> PlayerStats { get; set; }

  public virtual List<PlayerStat> GetCompletePlayerStats(IQueryable<Stat> stats)
    {
        var allStats = new List<PlayerStat>();
        var playerStatIds = PlayerStats.Select(ps => ps.PlayerStatistic.Id).ToList();
        if (playerStatIds.Count == 0)
        {
            allStats.AddRange(stats.Select(stat => new PlayerStat() {PlayerStatistic = stat, XP = 0}));
        }
        else
        {
            var zeroStats = stats.Where(s => !playerStatIds.Contains(s.Id)).ToList();

            allStats.AddRange(zeroStats.Select(zeroStat => new PlayerStat() {PlayerStatistic = zeroStat, XP = 0}));
            allStats.AddRange(PlayerStats);
        }

        return allStats;
    }

}
public class PlayerStat : EntityBase{
  public virtual Stat PlayerStatistic { get; set; }
  public virtual double XP { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to admit, I dont really see a major drawback in your class design so far. Of course I dont have any insight in the greater picture and how your game is designed, since this is only a little section of it.

However, you said it is the `GetCompletePlayerStats` that you dont really like. I had to read it several times to understand what you are trying to do here. If I saw that right, you just want to return a `PlayerStat` object corresponding to each given `Stat` object. I guess `Stat` has an `Id` field (you are using it in your method) to compare two of them for semantic equality.

Given, that I made the right assumptions so far (unfortunately, you didnt provide much info), the method can be simplified to something like:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<PlayerStat> GetCompletePlayerStats(IEnumerable<Stat> stats)
{
    foreach(Stat stat in stats)
        yield return PlayerStats.FirstOrDefault(s => stat.Id == s.PlayerStatistic.Id) ?? 
                     new PlayerStat() {PlayerStatistic = stat, XP = 0};
    yield break;
}
```

This method here doesnt require a `IQueryable` but rather a `IEnumerable` to iterate over via a `foreach` loop, and yield out the corresponding `PlayerStats` object if there is one, or create a new one with XP set to 0 otherwise (The null-coalescing operator `??` is very useful in those cases).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah, that'd work, although I have some gripes with it: firstly, calling FirstOrDefault() in a loop is effectively doing a nested-loop join (one explicit loop and another loop inside FirstOrDefault) which has really bad performance with larger sets. For a small number of stats this won't matter, but I was bitten by this kind of traps too many times that I just try to avoid them whenever I can. Secondly, it gives out a lazy enumerable which will be re-evaluated on each call, which might not be what you want. And thirdly, the yield break as the last statement in the method is redundant.

Comment: @Avish: Youre right, the `yield break;` is indeed redundant. But I dont really agree with you about the lazy enumerable thing: You say it may not be what the op wants, but why can you assume creating a list is what the op wants? We dont have any info about that. If we work on large data sets (as you said), a lazy enum may be much more appropriate if he only enumerates the results once. If he wants to reuse the resulting set, he can still call it like: `GetCompletePlayerStats(stats).ToList()`. It is more flexible than just returning a `IList<>`, it assumes something the caller might not want.

Comment: @Avish: Your solution has a better growth rate: Creating the dictionary takes O(m) time, but afterwards every `ContainsKey` call is in O(1). So the overall method is in O(m + n), whereas my solution takes a much worse O(m*n). However I dont believe we are working on sufficiently large datasets to justify this in the first place. What you are doing here is premature optimization. With small datasets my algorithm may even be faster (didnt test it - just a speculation). However, I want to say: it is generally better to optimize with a profiler *afterwards* if any performance problems occur...

Comment: @Philip: you are absolutely right on both counts -- a lazy enumerable is more flexible than a list, and creating a dictionary there is premature optimization. However, these are both examples of patterns that I tend to avoid since they can easily come back to bite you later in more complex situations without you noticing. I find the general principles "don't expose lazy enumerables unless you know exactly who'll use them" and "don't join by nested loops when dataset size is unknown" to be good rules of thumb in the general case. Of course each specific case should be judged independently.

Comment: Also, 100% agree that you should only invest in optimizing after you know what hurts you and only with a profiler. But I don't regard this as optimization, just sensible coding. By that I mean that it doesn't cost any extra effort, loss of readiblity or runtime performance to code it this way than that way, and in this case I prefer to just code it the "performant" way the first time around. I'm not "wasting" anything by "optimizing" it. Compare with how you'd put an expression into a variable to avoid evaluating it more than once, even though the performance gain is negligible.

Comment: The real solution is to have a one-liner extension method that does a 1:1 outer join (akin to Join() but with non-matches yielded as well), so that the easiest way to do it is also the most readable and most performant. Once you have that, you can have the implementation choose whether to do a nested loops join or a hash join based on input size (but this should only be done after you've experienced a performance issue stemming from such a join).

Comment: @Avish: 100% Ack :) Hope this discussion has showed the op that he has to find a good balance between all those facts and decide what fits his game best.

Comment: Great samples and great discussion. Thanks guys. Looks like I can only check one but I am keeping both snippets in my back pocket so I can implement either one in the future depending on circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

With the existing design, this method can be simplified thus:

```
public virtual IList<PlayerStat> GetCompletePlayerStats(IEnumerable<Stat> stats)
{
   // build a dictionary of existing stats by ID to facilitate 
   // the join with requested stats (effectively doing a hash join)
   var playerStatsById = PlayerStats.ToDictionary(ps => ps.PlayerStatistic.Id);

   // for each requested stat, return either the corresponding player stat 
   // or a zero stat if one isn't found, maintaining the original order of stats
   return stats
       .Select(s => playerStatsById.ContainsKey(s.Id) ? 
           playerStatsById[s.Id] : 
           new PlayerStat { PlayerStatistic = s, XP = 0 })
       .ToList();
}
```

Note that since this is effectively an outer-join operation (you're joining `stats` with `PlayerStats` but you also need the non-matches to yield as zero) you can also do it with LINQ's GroupJoin() operation, although I suspect that would be much less readable.

What does bother me about your design is the ambiguity of names, for example you have both the `PlayerStat` class and the `PlayerStatistic` property and they mean subtly different things; consider naming things differently and things might look better; in fact that's probably the best design advice I can give you, for any situation :)